# Is there a tool like Context Reverso for Esperanto?

Tags: translation

I don't need a translator, but a tool to search examples of sentences in Esperanto. The English translation is not really important. What matters is the possibility to find a lot of occurrences in many books, articles, etc.

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Do you mean "Reverso Context" (https://context.reverso.net)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vi havas la [Tekstaron de Esperanto](https://tekstaro.com), kies tekstamaso nuntempe ampleksas 10.470.329 da vortoj.

Laŭ [Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekstaro_de_Esperanto):

> La Tekstaro de Esperanto estas tekstaro (aŭ korpuso) de Esperanto, tio
> estas granda kolekto de tre diversaj tekstoj destinita al lingvistika
> esplorado pri Esperanto.

[Jen](https://tekstaro.com/tekstaro.html#priskribo) pli da informoj pri la projekto.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Glosbe. A couple of examples:

English to Esperanto:
https://glosbe.com/en/eo/exaggerated

Esperanto to English:
https://glosbe.com/eo/en/troigi

Answer (score 1):

Tatoeba is a large database of sentences and translations. Its content is ever-growing and results from the voluntary contributions of thousands of members.  https://tatoeba.org/